# Is there a way to override Tab functionality with fallback?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm working on Emmet.io support for the Monaco editor, and I'd like to have the autocomplete functionality behind the `Tab` key. However sometimes there are no autocompletions available, in that case I want to have the old Tab functionality.

Is there a way to override the `Tab` key, but use the old functionality if there are no suggestions by Emmet?

Thanks in advance!